# connecting mongoDB with Logstash Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, plugins, elasticsearch, logstash

I need help in installing MongoDB input plugin in logstash and the config file to connect with MongoDB. I am using ElasticSearch-Logstash in Windows Os.

> I have the Logstash-input-MongoDB plugin zip file. what are the steps for manual installation.

Answer (score 3):

First you should know that there is no official mongodb input plugin for logstash. Please take a look at [logstash's official plugin list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html).

I don't know where you got your zip file but you should use [logstash's built-in plugin manager](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/working-with-plugins.html) to install new plugins. The manual installation is much more complex. Use the following command to install a community based mongodb input plugin:

```
$LS_HOME/bin/plugin install logstash-input-mongodb
```

It will install [this RubyGem](https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-input-mongodb) for you. According to its documentation (which can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb)) it could be used like this:

```
input {
  mongodb {
    uri => 'mongodb://10.0.0.30/my-logs?ssl=true'
    path => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/logstash_sqlite.db'
    collection => 'events_'
    unpack_mongo_id => true
    batch_size => 5000
  }
}
```

However, since this is a non-official plugin you might experience some [bugs](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb/issues).

Comment: may i know which path does this line mean {path => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/logstash_sqlite.db'}

Comment: I am getting an error like "uninitialized constant Mongo::URI" when running the logstash for connecting mongodb using logstash-input-mongodb plugin. can you help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Could be the same bug as in `logstash-output-mongodb`. I've posted an answer to this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652436/unable-to-start-logstash-using-mongodb-config/31653965#31653965

Comment: ya i have tried that but it does not work for input plugin. output plugin is to add a document to mongodb right?

Comment: is "my-logs" name of database in "uri => 'mongodb://10.0.0.30/my-logs?ssl=true'" ?

Comment: @php.khan Yes. *my-logs* is the database. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score 1):

The use of "LS_HOME/bin/plugin" is deprecated and will be removed in a feature release. Please use "LS_HOME/bin/logstash-plugin".

You can install this plugin using command given below:

```
cd LS_HOME/bin/ && sudo ./logstash-plugin install logstash-input-mongodb
```